# How to add event handler and other attributes to select_month and select_year in rails 4.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to add event handler to select tag  with **select_month** tag in rails 4. And also i want add custom attributes to select tag how can i add ??

Can somebody explain through code ?

Example how o/p should be:

```
    <select id="test" name="test" onchange="test()" testing="testing">
           <option value="1">One</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: @Beerlington : Both are different questions. That is select_tab and this is select_month tag.

Comment: The questions are different, but the answer should be the same in both cases since both helpers take html_options as their last argument.